# Python - Unable to create session with Selenium standalone server with htmlunitdriver

Tags: java, python, selenium

I'm trying to use selenium remote standalone server with htmlUnit driver with a python script.
First of all I start the standalone server with htmlUnit driver

```
java -cp htmlunit-driver-2.35.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.0.jar
```

> 09:28:31.731 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.0, revision: 2ecb7d9a
>   09:28:31.810 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
>   2019-05-08 09:28:31.857:INFO::main: Logging initialized @317ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
>   09:28:32.059 INFO [WebDriverServlet.] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
>   09:28:32.543 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444

After that I try to use htmlunit driver in my pyhton script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'htmlunit', 'version': '2','javascriptEnabled': True})
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

But I receive this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create session from {
>     "desiredCapabilities": {
>       "browserName": "htmlunit",
>       "javascriptEnabled": true,
>       "version": "2"
>     },
>     "capabilities": {
>       "firstMatch": [
>         {
>           "browserName": "htmlunit"
>         },
>         {
>           "browserName": "htmlunit",
>           "browserVersion": "2"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
>   Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-xxxx', ip: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>   Stacktrace:
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$4 (NewSessionPipeline.java:76)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow (None:-1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$5 (NewSessionPipeline.java:75)
>       at java.util.Optional.orElseGet (None:-1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession (NewSessionPipeline.java:73)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute (BeginSession.java:65)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0 (WebDriverServlet.java:235)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (None:-1)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (None:-1)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (None:-1)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (None:-1)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)

I seem to have followed the documentation correctly, but I don't understand where the error could be. 
Can you tell me how can I solve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [`java` command line documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#jar)

> When you use the `-jar` option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and **other class path settings are ignored**.

So you need to amend the command you're using to launch [Selenium Grid](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Grid+Execution+with+Selenium) to look like:

```
java -cp "htmlunit-driver-2.35.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3
```

I would also recommend changing this line:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities={'browserName': 'htmlunit', 'version': '2','javascriptEnabled': True})
```

to this one:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNITWITHJS)
```

this way your script has a better chance to survive future libraries upgrade

Comment: Double check your syntax and presence of the files. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVPtm.png. You might also need to change `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` to `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.0.jar` if you don't want to upgrade to the latest Selenium version at this stage